# Search columns for values to copy specified data into new tab (structure)

Tags: excel, vba

I have to cleanse and restructure master data.

The base file is a list with master data structured like this:
plant number / plant name / master data field1 / master data field2 / etc..
(105 columns, column 1-2 = "basic value" of plants, constantly given. Column 3-105 = empty or filled value in cells to be cleansed).

**Macros job:**
Search every column/row (Column C-DB, 3-106) and if it finds a value in a cell:
Copy the plant number and the plant description from column A & B in the row where a value was found, the value found in the cell such as the column title in which the value was found. Then it should transport these values into the structure in a new tab (copy paste):

**New tab structure:**
plant nr / plant name / master data field name / master data field value

It basically should loop through the whole file and create that desired new list in the other tab with only "Plant Nr, Plant Name, Master Data Field Name, Master Data Field Value" (Switch from columns to rows). There are 25k plants (rows) and 103 master data fields (columns).

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone interessted for similar problem, this one worked perfectly:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ROW As Integer
Dim COLUMN As Integer
Dim Next_Result_Row

ROW = 2
COLUMN = 3
Next_Result_Row = 2

Dim Current_Header As String
Dim Inv_No As String
Dim Eq_Bez As String




Worksheets("Result").Range("A1:DZ50000").Clear

Worksheets("Result").Cells(1, 1) = "Inventarnummer"
Worksheets("Result").Cells(1, 2) = "Equipmentbezeichnung"
Worksheets("Result").Cells(1, 3) = "Characteristic"
Worksheets("Result").Cells(1, 4) = "Value"

While Worksheets("Base").Cells(ROW, 1).Value <> ""

COLUMN = 3

Inv_No = Worksheets("Base").Cells(ROW, 1)
Eq_Bez = Worksheets("Base").Cells(ROW, 2)

While Worksheets("Base").Cells(1, COLUMN).Value <> ""
Current_Header = Worksheets("base").Cells(1, COLUMN).Value

If Worksheets("Base").Cells(ROW, COLUMN) <> "" Then
Worksheets("Result").Cells(Next_Result_Row, 1) = Inv_No
Worksheets("Result").Cells(Next_Result_Row, 2) = Eq_Bez
Worksheets("Result").Cells(Next_Result_Row, 3) = Current_Header
Worksheets("Result").Cells(Next_Result_Row, 4) = Worksheets("base").Cells(ROW, COLUMN).Value
Next_Result_Row = Next_Result_Row + 1
End If

COLUMN = COLUMN + 1
Wend

ROW = ROW + 1

Wend


End Sub
```